# Unable to start PostgreSQL in Ubuntu 22

Tags: postgresql

I am unable to start PostgreSQL in Ubuntu 22. Status i get is,

```
root@NOC:/var/log/postgresql# systemctl status postgresql
â— postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-01-03 22:51:08 PKT; 3min 56s ago
   Main PID: 20422 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 5ms

Ø¬Ù†ÙØ±ÛŒ 03 22:51:08 NOC systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Ø¬Ù†ÙØ±ÛŒ 03 22:51:08 NOC systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Whereas, log file says below. Someone please advise.

```
2023-01-03 22:02:05.015 PKT [5770] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, co>
2023-01-03 22:02:05.015 PKT [5770] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-01-03 22:02:05.131 PKT [5770] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-01-03 22:02:05.636 PKT [5771] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-03 22:01:45 PKT
2023-01-03 22:02:05.689 PKT [5770] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-01-03 22:11:14.737 PKT [5770] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-01-03 22:11:16.010 PKT [5770] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-01-03 22:11:16.018 PKT [5770] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 5777) exited with exit code 1
2023-01-03 22:11:16.019 PKT [5772] LOG:  shutting down
2023-01-03 22:11:16.553 PKT [5770] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-01-03 22:11:29.193 PKT [6553] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, co>
2023-01-03 22:11:29.194 PKT [6553] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-01-03 22:11:29.276 PKT [6553] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-01-03 22:11:29.555 PKT [6554] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-01-03 22:11:16 PKT
2023-01-03 22:11:29.950 PKT [6553] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-01-03 22:11:38.090 PKT [6553] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-01-03 22:11:38.437 PKT [6553] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-01-03 22:11:38.442 PKT [6553] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 6560) exited with exit code 1
2023-01-03 22:11:38.445 PKT [6555] LOG:  shutting down
2023-01-03 22:11:41.103 PKT [6553] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: What does the Postgres' systemd unit file look like? Did you try starting it using `pg_ctl`?

Comment: It looks like someone or something commanded your database server to shutdown.  I don't know how to correlate that with your systemd log though.  What is the NOK timezone?

Comment: pg_ctl didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Debian, and some derivative distributions, such as Ubuntu, every PostgreSQL instance (cluster) belongs to an instantiated template service of the form `postgresql@version-clustername`.

For example, `postgresql@14-main` represents a PostgreSQL 14 server instance (cluster), with the cluster name `main` (which is the default cluster name).

The service `postgresql` is only a catch-all service. If you start or stop it, all PostgreSQL instances will be started or stopped. You cannot, however, use `systemctl status postgresql` to check whether any PostgreSQL servers are running, even if you only have a single PostgreSQL server.

You should always check the status of the particular instantiated service, for example: `systemctl status postgresql@14-main`.

To check all services for PostgreSQL, you may run `systemctl list-units "postgresql*"`.

For more information on instantiated services, please see [my answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1119445/574262) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

use pg_ctl start，That's all right. You can try it. I always use this command.

```
pg_ctl start
```

[image]